# Microphone stops working in libvirt

Tags: virtualization, 20.04, microphone, qemu

I had a Windows 10 running in libvrit (qemu) in ubuntu 18.04 which worked perfectly fine. I upgrade the ubuntu to 20.04 then I experience a problem with the microphone inside the VM.

The mic works fine initially when the VM boots up. However, if I use the mic (e.g., skype for business) for a few minutes, the mic will stop working. Nobody can hear me talking.

When I check the libvirt log, I see some entries like these:

```
audio: live=138449 hw->conv_buf->size=1920
A bug was just triggered in audio_get_avail
Context:
audio: live=138963 sw->hw->conv_buf->size=1920
A bug was just triggered in audio_pcm_hw_get_live_in
Context:
audio: live=138963 hw->conv_buf->size=1920
A bug was just triggered in audio_get_avail
Context:
audio: live=139448 sw->hw->conv_buf->size=1920
```

The log entries will stop eventually if I stop using the mic and the mic will be back to normal.

Does anyone know how to fix this issue?

Answer (score 0):

This was a bug related to the `qemu` and it got fixed on the newer version of it.
So you could use newer version of `Ubuntu` like `22.04` to solve your issue.